# How to register a service worker via cdn script. How to register service worker using external url

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

I have a cdn script file that should handles push notification settings for client websites.

```
    // cdn sdk.js
    const register = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("https://my_cdn_address.com/sw.js", {
        scope: "/",
    });
```

but i got this error:

```
The origin of the provided scriptURL ('https://my_cdn_address.com') does not match the current origin ('https://my_client_website.com').
```

Comment: As the error says, you won't be able to load a service worker from another domain, and there is no possible way to bypass this.

Comment: I know that. but i need to find a way to register an external service worker file.

Comment: @spProgrammer did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just Create a local service-worker.js and put your script in it like this.

importScripts(
"https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js"
);

Comment: I don't have access to local. Our clients using our sdk and they want this sdk register a service worker itself.

Answer (score 0):

##### Use a public CDN!

###### if you don't know what a CDN (Content Delivery Network) is [look here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjLpui5p_H7AhVPg_0HHdJ-C6QQFnoECBQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FContent_delivery_network&usg=AOvVaw0eAXFW9FJUk9LSyGpWmsy1)

---

###### there is 2 way to use public cdn :

###### 1. [unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com/)

###### unpkg is a fast, global content delivery network for everything on npm. Use it to quickly and easily load any file from any package using a URL like:

```js
" unpkg.com/:package@:version/:file "
```

###### so you can just publish an sw.js file and use it by unpkg to deliver it.

---

###### 2. [jsdelivr.com](https://www.jsdelivr.com)

###### with this website you can:

- load any project hosted on npm
- load any GitHub release, commit, or branch
- load any plugin from the WordPress.org plugins SVN repo

###### for example  you can load a package published in [npm](https://npmjs.com) like this:

```js
" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/package@version/file "
```

###### the intersting feature in jsdelivr is it can minfied your filed even if it's not exist

```js
// add ".min" to any JS/CSS file to get a minified version
// if one doesn't exist, we'll generate it for you
" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/src/core.min.js "
```

###### if your code hosted in Github just do this:

```js
" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/{username}/{repo@version}/{file} "
```

###### example:

```js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/jquery/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```